# Curvature of a regular parametrization

Tags: multivariable-calculus, differential-geometry

> Prove that if $\mu: [a,b] \to \mathbb{R}^n$ is a regular
>   parametrization of a curve then the curvature at $\mu(t)$ is given
>   by: $$\kappa(t) =
>  \left|\left|\left(\frac{\mu'(t)}{||\mu'(t)||}\right)'\frac{1}{||\mu'(t)||}\right|\right|.$$

A regular parametrization is when $\mu'(t)\ne 0$ for all $t \in \mathbb{R}$.

I know that I must use arc length to show this but I don't know how to apply it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way I learned it, the curvature $\kappa$ of a curve such as $\mu(t)$ is *the magnitude of rate of change of the unit tangent vector $\mathbf{u}$  with respect to the distance or arc length $s$ along the curve*.  Now in the present case, the vector $\mu'(t)$ is tangent to $\mu(t)$ at $t$, so the unit tangent vector is

$\mathbf{u} = \frac{\mu'(t)}{\Vert \mu'(t) \Vert}$,

whence

$\kappa = \Vert \frac{d \mathbf{u}}{ds} \Vert$;

but

$\frac{d \mathbf{u}}{ds} = \frac{d \mathbf{u}}{dt} \frac{dt}{ds}$,

and since $\mu'(t)$ is the tangent vector to the curve $\mu(t)$, we have

$\frac{ds}{dt} = \Vert \mu'(t) \Vert$,

from which follows that

$\frac{dt}{ds} = \frac{1}{\Vert \mu'(t) \Vert};$

note we have used the given property that the parametrization is regular, i.e. that
$\mu'(t) \ne 0$, hence $\Vert \mu'(t) \Vert \ne 0$, in this last step to (albeit implicitly) infer that the function $s(t)$ which takes the $t$ parameter to arc length $s$,
is invertible to $t(s)$, and that the derivative $\frac{dt}{ds} = (\frac{ds}{dt})^{-1}$.  We thus have, bringing it all together,

$\kappa = \Vert \frac{d\mathbf{u}}{ds} \Vert = \Vert \frac{d\mathbf{u}}{dt} \frac{1}{\Vert \mu'(t) \Vert} \Vert = \Vert (\frac{\mu'(t)}{\Vert \mu'(t) \Vert})' \frac{1}{\Vert \mu'(t) \Vert} \Vert$,

which is the desired result.  Note that here and throughout the prime symbol (') denotes differentiation with respect to $t$.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Than you very much! This is a very nice explanation.

Comment: @Lays:  my pleasure, sir!

Comment: Mr. Lewis, if you don't mind elaborating a bit more, is this formula independent of the parametrization? If so, how?

Comment: @Lays:  the result it gives is parametrization-independent, as long as $\mu'(t) \ne 0$.  Reason:  othet than $t$, all entities appearing here are *geometric invariants*, whose definition does not depend on any particular coordinates.  This includes $s$, $\mathbf{u}$, and $\kappa$.   $t$ *is* a coordinate dependent quantity, but the factor $\frac{1}{\Vert \mu'(t) \Vert}$  compensates for this coordinate dependence.

Comment: @Lays:  previous comment a blunder.  Deleted.  Sorry for the hassle. ;)

Comment: @Lays:  must sleep now.  If you need more info, ping me tomorrow via a comment and I'll get back to you.  Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

Use the chain rule. In particular, $ \frac{d}{ds} = \frac{dt}{ds} \frac{d}{dt} = \frac{1}{||\mu'(t) ||} \frac{d}{dt} $.